# When attempting to play sound, computer continuously plays Windows Error sound

Tags: python, windows, audio, winsound

I've tried multiple forms of playing sound. I first tried using playsound. Here's my code:

```
import playsound
from playsound import playsound

playsound('Sunflower.mp3')
```

I've also attempted using winsound, although using my computer's native mp3 player isn't ideal.

```
import winsound

Sunflower = 'Sunflower.mp3'
winsound.Playsound(Sunflower, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

In both cases, when I try to play the file back I only hear the windows error noise. The same occurs when I try to use a wav version of that file. Curiously, sound does play if I use a shorter .wav file.

Comment: try using an absolute path with backslashes

Comment: …and double each backslash in the path.